# Auto-complete / Type-ahead while editing tables in Org-Mode?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp, org-mode, code-completion

While editing Microsoft Excel cells, the software offers auto-complete suggestions based on previous entries on the same column.

Is there a similar short-cut in Org-mode, where it auto-completes/type-aheads (with bash-shell like disambiguation)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, see the Emacs manual, node `Dynamic Abbrevs` (`C-h r g dyn TAB`).  This is not specific to Org mode; it works in pretty much any mode.

Answer (score 0):

[`company`](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode) also handles this fine, you just have to enable it in `org-mode` buffers.